# Entity framework add new entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I unable to insert a record in table

```
public class KPITable
{

    [Key]        
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Query { get; set; }
    public string TableName { get; set; }
}

public class KPITableMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<KPITable>
{
    public KPITableMap()
    {
        ToTable("EIS_KPI", AppUtility.EISMDBSchemaName);
        Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("KPI_ID");           
        Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("NAME").HasMaxLength(20);
        Property(t => t.Query).HasColumnName("QUERY").HasMaxLength(20);
        Property(t => t.TableName).HasColumnName("TABLE_NAME").HasMaxLength(20);

    }
}
```

I am getting error when i try to add new entity

> *A null store-generated value was returned for a non-nullable member
>   'Id' of type     'EISM.Database.Models.KPITable*

```
var newEntity = new KPITable();
newEntity.Id = 55;
                newEntity.Name = data.Name;
                newEntity.Query = data.Query;
                newEntity.TableName = data.TableName;
_dbContext.KPIs.Attach(newEntity);
                _dbContext.Entry(newEntity).State = EntityState.Added;
                _dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: This might not be the answer, but you can try changing `Id` to `int? Id` and try the operation again.

Comment: Is the ID column named  KPI_ID in the database? Also : are you sure that your mapping is loaded correctly?

Comment: ID column mapped KPI_ID in database table. the mapping is loaded correctly. I am able to retrieve and update the record, only problem is inserting new record. @Nilesh yes i tried making int? for Id but did not work

Comment: I see you already found a solution but, you should try @Dannydust answer. Thats the correct way to add new entities.

Comment: I have tried Dannydust solution, but did not work. find my comments below Dannydust solution

Answer (score 12, accepted):

this has resolved my problem

```
[Key]     
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

OR you can just remove this line

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var newEntity = new KPITable();
newEntity.Id = 55;
                newEntity.Name = data.Name;
                newEntity.Query = data.Query;
                newEntity.TableName = data.TableName;
_dbContext.KPIs.AddObject(newEntity);
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Attach is for existing entities (when they are detached, or when you want to attach it to another entity).

AddObject is for new entities.

Comment: Hi, I am using EF 5 so the equivalent for AddObjects is     _dbContext.Set<KPITable>().Add(newEntity); but this still not worked